# In post deployment condition, using rest api task, how can i defined success criteria based on value of node within xml response?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I'm trying to create a post deployment gate at the end of a stage in a release pipeline using a REST Api task, and I need to define a success criteria based on a value in the api response which, unfortunately, is in XML.

I read this:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/conditions?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml

And this:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops

So, say the api xml response looked liked this

```
<scan>
  <result>
    <errorCount>3</errorCount>
    <severity>medium</severity>
  </result>
</scan>
```

i tried an expression like this for my success criteria

```
eq(scan.result.severity,'low')
```

but when it ran, the gate failed and the logs show an error of "Error parsing API response into a JSON object." I had put "Accept":"application/xml" in the headers section of the task hoping it would recognize the requested format to know how to parse it. I know XML is old, but is it not supported in this task? Or am I doing it wrong?

P.S. I also really want an email notification to go out if the gate fails and can't find an option in the notifications that appears to provide that ability. Does it exist?

Comment: you'd probably need to use a script step